# how to find all column records are same or not in group by column in SQL

Tags: sql, group-by

How to find all column values are same in **Group by** of rows in table

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp (ID int,Value char(1)) 
insert into #Temp  (ID ,Value ) ( Select 1  ,'A' union all  Select 1    ,'W' union all  Select 1    ,'I' union all  Select 2    ,'I' union all  Select 2    ,'I' union all  Select 3    ,'A' union all  Select 3    ,'B' union all  Select 3    ,'1'  )

select * from #Temp
```

**Sample Table:**

[image: **Sample Table:**]

How to find all column value of 'Value' column are same or not if group by 'ID' Column.

Ex: `select ID from #Temp group by ID`
For ID 1 - Value column records are *A, W, I* - **Not Same** 
For ID 2 - Value column records are *I, I*    - **Same**
For ID 3 - Value column records are *A, B, 1* - **Not Same**

I want the query to get a result like below

[image]

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Also, what if there are two of the same values and one different value per ID?

Comment: @BJones, to me, that is still "Not Same".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When all items in the group are the same, `COUNT(DISTINCT Value)` would be `1`:

```
SELECT Id
,   CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT Value)=1 THEN 'Same' ELSE 'Not Same' END AS Result
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Id
```

Comment: Concise and intuitive, I like this solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using T-SQL, perhaps this will work for you:

```
SELECT t.ID, 
       CASE WHEN MAX(t.RN) > 1 THEN 'Same' ELSE 'Not Same' END AS GroupResults
FROM(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID, VALUE ORDER BY ID) RN
    FROM @Temp 
    ) t
GROUP BY t.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Usally that's rather easy: Aggregate per ID and count distinct values or compare minimum and maximum value.

However, neither `COUNT(DISTINCT value)` nor `MIN(value)` nor `MAX(value)` take nulls into consideration. So for an ID having value 'A' and null, these would detect uniqueness. Maybe this is what you want or nulls don't even occur in your data.

But if you want nulls to count as a value, then select distinct values first (where null gets a row too) and count then:

```
select id, case when count(*) = 1 then 'same' else 'not same' end as result
from (select distinct id, value from #temp) dist
group by id
order by id;
```

Rextester demo: http://rextester.com/KCZD88697